# Error trying to create a custom tag with Jakarta EE 10 and Jakarta Faces 4

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, java-17

In the book "The Definitive Guide to Jakarta Faces in Jakarta EE 10: Building Java-Based Enterprise Web Applications" there is an example for creating a template using a custom tag and a `.xhtml` but when I try to run this example using Wildfly 27 and Jakarta faces 4, it throws this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()" because "document" is null
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()" because "document" is null
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@4.0.0.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:247)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@28.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()" because "document" is null
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@4.0.0.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:319)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@4.0.0.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:179)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()" because "document" is null
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@4.0.0.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:222)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@4.0.0.SP01//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:310)
    ... 22 more

11:58:12,227 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jakartaee-hello-world.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null"}}
```

First, I created the file apollo.taglib.xml in `WEB-INF` folder with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns:="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
                xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
                https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facelettaglibrary_4_0.xsd"
                version="4.0">
  <namespace>com.saukisoft.apollo.tags</namespace>
  <short-name>a</short-name>
  <tag>
    <description>Vertical box.</description>
    <tag-name>vbox</tag-name>
    <source>tags/vbox.xhtml</source>
    <attribute>
      <description>The space between items.</description>
      <name>gap</name>
      <required>false</required>
      <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
  <tag>
    <description>Horizontal box.</description>
    <tag-name>hbox</tag-name>
    <source>tags/hbox.xhtml</source>
    <attribute>
      <description>The space between items.</description>
      <name>gap</name>
      <required>false</required>
      <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

then I created two templates in `WEB-INF/tags`:

hbox.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="jakarta.faces.facelets">
  <div class="hstack gap-3">
    <ui:insert/>
  </div>
</ui:composition>
```

vbox.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="jakarta.faces.facelets">
  <div class="vstack gap-3">
    <ui:insert/>
  </div>
</ui:composition>
```

and finally, added the `context-param` in `web.xml` file describing the new taglib.xml file:

```
...
  <context-param>
    <param-name>jakarta.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/apollo.taglib.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
...
```

When starting Wildfly, the following error is thrown:

```
11:58:12,227 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jakartaee-hello-world.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null
    Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"org.w3c.dom.Document.getDocumentElement()\" because \"document\" is null"}}
```

Environment:

- Java 17
- Wildfly 27
- Jakarta EE 10
- Jakarta Faces 4

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Jakarta Faces 4.0 documentation, in the examples they doesn't use the `xmlns` attributes in the taglib.xml file. So, when I removed those attributes from the root tag, it started to work and the war artifact was deployed without problems. It's weird but the solution was to remove all `xmlns` attributes from the `facelet-taglib` root tag:

```
  <namespace>apollo.tags</namespace>
  <short-name>a</short-name>
  <tag>
    <description>Vertical box.</description>
    <tag-name>vbox</tag-name>
    <source>tags/vbox.xhtml</source>
    <attribute>
      <description>The space between items.</description>
      <name>gap</name>
      <required>false</required>
      <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
  <tag>
    <description>Horizontal box.</description>
    <tag-name>hbox</tag-name>
    <source>tags/hbox.xhtml</source>
    <attribute>
      <description>The space between items.</description>
      <name>gap</name>
      <required>false</required>
      <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Now it's up and running.